# Using Python to extract dictionary keys within a list

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, twitter

I received a list when inputting the following URL - http://api.twitter.com/1/trends/44418.json

The list contains multiple dictionaries, and I'm a bit confused with the list structure. I'm trying to obtain the values associated with the 'name' key.

For example:

"name":"#throwagrenade"
   "name":"Rebecca Black"
   "name":"#questionsihate"

I can write the code myself, I'm just trying to conceptually understand how to access dictionaries (and their key/value pairs) within a list.

Comment: Just a note, twitter uses a API v1.1 now that requires authentication. You can read more about accessing the trends [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1#110).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The first thing I would do when working with a big lump of json, is try to get it into a more readable format. [This online json formatting tool](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com) should do the job.

Here's some code that will get all the trend names:

```
import urllib2
import json

url = 'http://api.twitter.com/1/trends/44418.json'

# download the json string
json_string = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()

# de-serialize the string so that we can work with it
the_data = json.loads(json_string)

# get the list of trends
trends = the_data[0]['trends']

# print the name of each trend
for trend in trends:
    print trend['name']
```

Or you can do it all in one line:

```
names = [trend['name'] for trend in the_data[0]['trends']]

for name in names:
    print name
```

Both will result in:

```
#throwagrenade
Rebecca Black
Eric Abidal
#questionsihate
#juniordoctors
Smiley Culture
Lily Allen
Wes Brown
Pandev
Ray Wilkins
```

**Relevant reading:**

[Python docs on json](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) (although you should only really need `json.loads()`)

[*Dive Into Python*](http://diveintopython.net/)'s  sections on [lists](http://diveintopython.net/getting_to_know_python/lists.html) and [dictionaries](http://diveintopython.net/getting_to_know_python/dictionaries.html).

Comment: thanks! great response, appreciate the extra reading material as well.

Comment: I'd also recommend the new [Dive Into Python 3](https://diveintopython3.ep.io/) - dictionaries and lists are mentioned in the section [Chapter 2. Native Datatypes](https://diveintopython3.ep.io/native-datatypes.html).

Answer (score 8):

Well, for a start, that link gives you JSON, so you'll need to deserialize it with the `json` library:

```
data = json.loads(response_data)
```

Now you simply have a list of dictionaries. You can easily iterate through the list with a `for` loop. On each iteration, you have a normal dictionary, from which you can get the value corresponding to the `name` key with the usual dictionary syntax.

You can do the whole thing at once with a simple list comprehension:

```
names = [item['name'] for item in data]
```

Comment: The list of dictionaries containing the names are not in the root of the data, they are in `[0]['trends']`

Answer (score 4):

```
import urllib2
import json

url = 'http://api.twitter.com/1/trends/44418.json'
data = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
j = json.loads(data)

names = [d['name'] for d in j[0]['trends']]
```

results in

```
names = [u'#throwagrenade', u'Rebecca Black', u'#questionsihate',
    u'#thingsthatdontgotogether', u'Eric Abidal', u'Smiley Culture',
    u'Ray Wilkins', u'Wes Brown', u'Twenty Twelve', u'Marseille']
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a JSON file, so you need to use a JSON parser to read it. There is [a parser](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) in Python 2.7 - just `import json`. With that structure, you can then manipulate it from Python.

If you really don't care where in the structure the `name` keys are, you could either recurse through the tree looking for them (`if key == "name"`), or perhaps use a regular expression.

The regular expression will be much pain, though, because of the need to include escaped characters in a match.

Comment: The idea of using a regular expression gives me a headache just thinking about it!