# JSON Object parsing: Loop through dynamic data

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON object as follows:

```
{u'2015-05-11': 2, u'2015-05-04': 1}
```

Here the dates can vary, i.e., I can query for multiple dates.

I want to extract the numbers in the object and add them. So in this example I want to extract `2` and `1` and them up to get the result `3`.

Another example:

```
{u'2015-05-11': 6, u'2015-05-04': 0}
```

Here the answer will be `6 + 0 = 6`.

Another example of the JSON object with multiple dates:

```
{u'2015-04-27': 0, u'2015-05-11': 2, u'2015-05-04': 1}
```

Here the answer will be: `0 + 2 + 1 = 3`

I want to loop through the JSON object and extract all the numbers. I've read the answers provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12353288/python-json-get-values) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318747/using-python-to-extract-dictionary-keys-within-a-list). The problem is the, the JSON object that I have does not have a fixed key that I can query.

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are all Python dicts, not JSON objects.

Since you don't seem to care about the keys at all, you can just get the values and sum them:

```
result = sum(data.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure it's a json data, the data is like as below:

```
'{"2015-05-11": 2, "2015-05-04": 1}'
```

Convert json to dict:

```
data = json.loads(a)
# {u'2015-05-11': 2, u'2015-05-04': 1}
```

According to your question, solve the problem.

```
result = sum(data.values())
# 3
```

Answer (score -2):

Daniel's answer provides you the solution youre looking for but you should also know that you can iterate through a Python dict with enumerate.

```
for value, key in enumerate(your_dict):
    print value, key
```